# MySQL creating a complex query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

I have three tables, a users table, test_sessions table, and a courses table.

I need to create a report that has a complete list of users. In the courses table, some courses have a field 'track' = 1. If it is equal to 1, I need a column for that course in the report.

The test_sessions table has a complete_date field as well as the user_id and course_id.

For the report I need something like this:

```
______|Tracked Course 1|Tracked Course 2 |Tracked Course 3
User 1|complete date   |complete date    |complete date
User 2|complete date   |complete date    |complete date
User 3|complete date   |complete date    |complete date
```

I want to be able to write a single query to do this, is it possible?

Comment: Can you show us the design of the three tables with some test values in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a `PIVOT`, but MySQL doesn't have a `PIVOT` so you will need to replicate it using an aggregate and a `CASE` statement.  If you know the course name's that you want to get the values of you can hard-code it:

```
select u.userName,
  max(case when c.coursename = 'Course 1' then s.completed_date end) Course1,
  max(case when c.coursename = 'Course 2' then s.completed_date end) Course2,
  max(case when c.coursename = 'Course 3' then s.completed_date end) Course3
from users u
left join test_sessions s
  on u.user_id = s.user_id
left join courses c
  on s.course_id = c.course_id
group by u.username
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d76d5/1)

If you have an unknown number of courses, then you can use a prepared statement, similar to this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when c.coursename = ''',
      coursename,
      ''' then s.completed_date end) AS ',
      coursename
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM courses;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT u.userName, ', @sql, ' 
                  from users u
                  left join test_sessions s
                    on u.user_id = s.user_id
                  left join courses c
                    on s.course_id = c.course_id
                  group by u.username');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d76d5/3)